# The connection between Kolmogorov complexity and mathematical logic

Tags: logic, big-list, incompleteness, kolmogorov-complexity

We know that Kolmogorov complexity has connections to mathematical logic since it can be used to prove the Gödel incompleteness results (Chaitin's Theorem and [Kritchman-Raz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4974)). Are there any other striking application of Kolmogorov complexity to mathematical logic?

Relatively simple examples like the ones I mentioned are preferred, but more complicated illustrations are also welcome!

(Cross-posted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368615/151697).)

Comment: You can start with Pavel Pudlak, [Logical Foundations of Mathematics and Computational Complexity (Springer, 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=obxDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA365), **Ch.5 The Complexity of Computations**.

Comment: Maybe useful also Oded Goldreich, [Computational complexity : A conceptual perspective (2008, Cambridge University Press)](https://books.google.it/books?id=c-LlnQEACAAJ)

Comment: FWIW I consider Kolmogorov complexity (and computability theory in general) part of mathematical logic already.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, sure. Let's say to _other_ areas of mathematical logic then :) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I found this question, here are two of my favorite relatively simple, yet lengthy, examples. The Kolmogorov complexity will be denoted $C(x)$.

---

> **Theorem**: *There are infinitely many primes.*

**Proof**: Suppose there isn't. The there are $k$ primes $p_{1},p_{2},...,p{k}$ for  $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, we can take any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and write it as a product of these $k$ primes: $$m = p^{e_{1}}_{1}...p^{e_{k}}_{k}.$$ Now, let $m$ be Kolmogorov random and have length $n$. We can describe $m$ by $e_{1},e_{2},...,e_{k}$. We claim that this gives a short description of $m$. First, $e_{i} \le $ log$m$, thus $|e_{i}| \le$ log$\cdot$log$m$. Hence $|\langle e_{1},...,e_{k}\rangle| \le 2k$log$\cdot$ log$m$. Therefore, as $m \le 2^{n+1}$, $|\langle e_{1},...,e_{k} \rangle| \le 2k$log$(n+1)$, so $C(m) \le 2k$log$(n+1)+c$ (for $c \in \mathbb{N}$). For large enough $n$, this contradicts $C(m) \ge$, which follows from the fact that $m$ is random. $\blacksquare$

---

One could say that the proof above is more complex than the original one. However, the following result is pretty close to the real
“prime number theorem” and, in my opinion, is definitely easier.

Let $p_{m}$ be the largest prime that divides $m$. The we can describe $m$ by specifying $p_{i}$ and $\frac{m}{p_{i}}$; and actually all we need is $i$ and $\frac{m}{p_{i}}$ since we can compute $p_{i}$ given $i$. for $m$ random, we have the following: $C(m) \le C(<i, \frac{m}{p_{i}}>) \le 2$log$|i|+|i|+|\frac{m}{p_{i}}|$, so log$m \le 2$log$\cdot$log$i+$log$i+$log$m -$log$p_{i}$. Cancelling gives us log$p_{i} \le$ log$i+2$log$\cdot$log$i$ which in turn gives $p_{i} \le i$$($log$i$$)^{2}$.

The classical theorem is that the $i$-th prime is below $i$ log $i$, so the above is pretty
close.
Interestingly, most strings are “close” to being random.

---

**EDIT**: Since I have realized, according to the comment on this answer, that these examples are *outside* mathematical logic. To make up for this, I provide the following [link](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/%7Echernov/ComplexityAndFormulas.pdf). This is a great .pdf that explores the usage of Kolmogorov complexity on logical operators and related formulae. Also, it gives some pretty neat diagrams of these ideas! I will keep the examples above to, hopefully, provide a good outside mathematical logic learning experience.

Comment: This is very neat, but it's really an application of Kolmogorov complexity *outside* of logic, which is not what the OP is asking for ("are there any other striking application of Kolmogorov complexity to mathematical logic?").

Comment: @NoahSchweber -  I think so too! and darn, you're right! I got too excited. Should I delete or keep this here since its still a nice application?

Comment: No, please let it up (although I won't award the bounty for it). I was already aware of these applications, and at first was very excited over them. However, a number theorist explained to me that both these results have simple proofs in elementary number theory as well, and that the connection doesn't really go further... but maybe someone else knows more about this.

Comment: @Jori - Sounds great. I added an edit to my post that included a link to a .pdf that is aimed more towards the application to mathematical logic.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/337922 for de-obfuscation of this proof.